# Mysql file system snapshot restore fails

Tags: mysql, backup, innodb

I am taking a snapshot of an AWS EBS volume which is a file system snapshot. This volume is used by mysql, mounted at /var/lib/mysql. When I run another instance of mysql with the backed up volume it fails to restore to correct state.

I have tried setting cache size and cache limit to zero. So that when I read from db it is read from actual disk and not cache (this is what I am hoping unless I am wrong)

```
SET GLOBAL query_cache_limit=0;
SET GLOBAL query_cache_size=0;
```

These are the logs when I start the new mysql container with the mounted volume snapshot:

```
2019-06-23 11:09:30 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.6.44) starting as process 1 ...
2019-06-23 11:09:30 1 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2019-06-23 11:09:30 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2019-06-23 11:09:30 1 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2019-06-23 11:09:30 1 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2019-06-23 11:09:30 1 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2019-06-23 11:09:30 1 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-06-23 11:09:30 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2019-06-23 11:09:30 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2019-06-23 11:09:30 1 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2019-06-23 11:09:30 1 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-06-23 11:09:30 1 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2019-06-23 11:09:30 1 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1633877 and 1633877 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1633887 in the ib_logfiles!
2019-06-23 11:09:30 1 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2019-06-23 11:09:30 1 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2019-06-23 11:09:30 1 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2019-06-23 11:09:30 1 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2019-06-23 11:09:30 1 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2019-06-23 11:09:30 1 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-06-23 11:09:30 1 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-06-23 11:09:30 1 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.44 started; log sequence number 1633887
2019-06-23 11:09:30 1 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2019-06-23 11:09:30 1 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2019-06-23 11:09:30 1 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2019-06-23 11:09:30 1 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2019-06-23 11:09:30 1 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2019-06-23 11:09:30 1 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@demo-7744bc55cd-swsft' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2019-06-23 11:09:30 1 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2019-06-23 11:09:30 1 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.44'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

I expect to get the same state of mysql as it was when I took snapshot.

Comment: As you can see the log says ```2019-06-23 11:09:30 1 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1633877 and 1633877 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1633887 in the ib_logfiles!``` which I think could be an issue.

Comment: The Query cache should be totally irrelevant.  The "log sequence number" is a serious problem.  Was the snapshot taken with AWS scripts?

Comment: It was done using aws api calls using golang library @RickJames